# How to set context parameters in a context xml file?

Tags: web-applications, jetty

I have a web application which relies on context or init parameters, which I run in Jetty.

I have found out how I can set these in the WEB-INF/web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>myParamName</param-name>
    <param-value>42</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Once I pack my web application into a .war file, I can no longer change these, so I have to somehow set the parameters in the servlet context xml file.

What I found out from the eclipse.jetty Wiki is this:

```
<Set name="initParameter">
    <Arg>myParamName</Arg>
    <Arg>42</Arg>
</Set>
```

But Jetty throws a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` when I try this.
What is the correct way of setting context parameters in Jetty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to do it such way:

```
<Call name="setInitParameter">
    <Arg>myParamName</Arg>
    <Arg>42</Arg>
</Call>
```